# Eclipse Kepler plugins - Offline Installation

Tags: eclipse, plugins, jenkins, glassfish

I am trying to install 2 eclipse plugins in offline mode(copy-paste) in Kepler.

I downloaded jenkins & glassfish from update sites in eclipse (lets say Eclipse 1). Later I copied the jenkins plugins (all folders & jars from plugins & features) separately in a folder; similar is done for glassfish.

Installation method - I extracted a fresh eclipse kepler(lets say Eclipse 2), tried to copy paste plugins & features of the Glassfish to my new eclipse. It worked well. But when I copied Jenkins related plugins, Glassfish server option disappeared from Server view.

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't extract data from update sites, the features in particular are not in the correct format for direct installation.

Instead open 'Help' > 'Install New Software'. Click 'Add...' on the 'Work with' line. Select 'Archive' on Add Repository dialog that opens and select the update site jar. When you click OK the main install dialog should show you what is available to install.